# Рисование по пикселям в PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Как можно, используя PyQt5, рисовать попиксельно?

Например есть триплет `ff ff ff` и нужно отрисовать пиксель по ним?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создается окно, его фон закрашивается черным цветом и в центре рисуется пиксель `#ffffff`:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QPainter
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class Widget(QWidget):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)

        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setBrush(Qt.black)
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())

        painter.setPen(QColor(0xff, 0xff, 0xff))
        painter.drawPoint(self.width() / 2, self.height() / 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Widget()
    w.resize(250, 150)
    w.move(300, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```